# scrollable table inside a bootstrap hstack

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a scrollable table inside a container with other components, but it didn't work as I expected. When only the table, it works perfectly fine. But I want to place another component below it, so `hstack` and `d-flex` crossed my mind. I've tried both but none of them worked.

I only want the table to scroll, not the component below it.
[image]

Here is the code that mainly use bootstrap:

```
 <div class="vstack gap-3">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="order table-responsive rounded-1 border border-secondary-subtle">
                    <table class="table m-0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">Sản phẩm</th>
                                <th>Giá</th>
                                <th>Số lượng</th>
                                <th>Tạm tính</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rounded-1 border border-secondary-subtle">
                <div class="hstack gap-3 px-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="pe-0 align-middle">
                        <label for="voucher" class="me-3 p-0 fw-bold fs-5 text-nowrap">
                            Mã giảm giá
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ps-0">
                        <div class="hstack border border-secondary-subtle rounded-pill mx-2">
                            <input type="text" class="inp" id="voucher" placeholder="Nhập voucher">
                            <button class="rounded-pill apply_btn">Áp dụng</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The only class with CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

I'm on my learning path about Front-End, so would love to receive any comment or other solutions for what I'm doing. Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar.
But wrapping a div won't scroll if the height is not set in pixels.

Bootstrap's responsive tables (`.table-responsive`) are designed for Horizontal scrolling. You will need to override some settings to get vertical scrolling.

I've also included some optional CSS for you to consider:

- sticky table headers
- styled scrollbars (for --web-kit-* browsers)

```css
.wrapper .table-responsive {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
 
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}


/* comment out to remove fixed header */
.wrapper .table-responsive {
  --header-height: 41px;
  scroll-padding-top: var(--header-height);
}

.wrapper .table-responsive table thead {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper .table-responsive table thead th {
  height: var(--header-height)
}


/* comment out to remove styled scroll bars */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  min-height: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #5d7b9d;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vstack gap-3">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="order table-responsive rounded-1 border border-secondary-subtle">
        <table class="table m-0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">Sản phẩm</th>
              <th>Giá</th>
              <th>Số lượng</th>
              <th>Tạm tính</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-1 border border-secondary-subtle">
      <div class="hstack gap-3 px-1 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="pe-0 align-middle">
          <label for="voucher" class="me-3 p-0 fw-bold fs-5 text-nowrap">
                            Mã giảm giá
                        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-0">
          <div class="hstack border border-secondary-subtle rounded-pill mx-2">
            <input type="text" class="inp" id="voucher" placeholder="Nhập voucher">
            <button class="rounded-pill apply_btn">Áp dụng</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```